# How to get more details out of Capybara at failure time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

My shopping list is...

- ruby-2.0.0-p247
- rails (4.0.1)
- rspec-rails (2.14.0)
- capybara (2.0.3)
- capybara-selenium-remote (0.0.1)

The point is RSpec feature-tests that drive Capybara, that drive a Firefox web browser hitting our website.

Now ogle this failing ... expectation:

```
old_date = 'November 16, 2013 04:00 pm'
expect(page).to have_field('somethingDate', with: old_date)
```

When it fails, it emits this:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_field('somethingDate', with: old_date)
   expected #has_field?("somethingDate", {:with=>"November 16, 2013 04:00 pm"}) \
  to return true, got false
```

The general question this: How to write an assertion that reveals `_everything_` it knows about a situation. Instead of almost NOTHING: "got false".

I would expect, based on my (cough) experience with `assert_select` and `assert_xpath`, to at least see a snip of the HTML around the fault point. If not, then maybe at LEAST the value that `has_field?` DID find in that field. (And keep in mind this is only RAILS FOUR, already...)

So the two sub-questions are:

- Would a different assertion tell me more? (If so, why is `has_field?` supposed to be the industry flagship assertion here?)
- Is there some way to configure or tune or plug-in `has_field?`, to emit more details at fault time?

Comment: Does the test pass without the `with:`?

Comment: Tx but that's not the question. I know how to `_manually_` diagnose the problem. My point is the `has_field` knows all kinds of stuff that it's not sharing with us. The easier tests are to fix, the more likely they stay online over time, after surprise failures.

Comment: I understand your question, I just wanted to make sure that `has_field?` was not providing more meaningful data because it had none to give, i.e. if there was no `somethingDate` on the page at all.

Comment: OMG I just checked & you'r right. has_field? does not even distinguish between a missing field, and a present field with a missing value.